# TF - Transform world frame update rate should be fastest

Tags: ros, frames, tf2, ros-indigo, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

I am basically doing a transformation from camera_link to world frame

Here is the message before the transformation in [camera_link] frame:

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 4.723000000
  frame_id: camera_link
uid: 0
position: 
  x: 1.10738
  y: -0.16057
  z: 0.241941
velocity: 
  x: -0.00120042
  y: 0.0169336
  z: 0.240961
diameter: 0.064
diameter_px: 26.401
covariance[]
  covariance[0]: 0.000693303
  covariance[1]: 0.000586575
  covariance[2]: 0.00238198
  covariance[3]: 0
  covariance[4]: 0
  covariance[5]: -0
confidence: 1
```

And this is the message after it was transformed: [in world]

```
header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 4.723000000
  frame_id: world
uid: 0
position: 
  x: 0.322941
  y: -0.21167
  z: 1.0397
velocity: 
  x: 0.321961
  y: -0.0341664
  z: 2.14828
diameter: 0.064
diameter_px: 26.401
covariance[]
  covariance[0]: 0.000693303
  covariance[1]: 0.000586575
  covariance[2]: 0.00238198
  covariance[3]: -4.13646e-13
  covariance[4]: 1.5708
  covariance[5]: 0
confidence: 1
```

Now actually the high velocities in the world frame could not be correct ....

I have only doubts on how this errors occur:

1. It is because of the different update rate:
   **rosrun tf view_frames**

[image: image description]

-> the world frame update rate should always be the fastest????

2. I did not set a seq in the header???
3. **rosrun tf tf_monitor camera_link world**

RESULTS: for camera_link to world
Chain is: camera_link -> camera_mount_link -> camera_footprint -> world
Net delay     avg = -0.0952712: max = 0

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291163/tf---transform-world-frame-update-rate-should-be-fastest/) by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2018-05-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-15**:
Can you give us some more details, what is the type of the message you are transforming and what code are you using to transform it. The magnitude of the velocity should be constant so there is definitely something wrong.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-05-15**:
Another comment about the rates shown by `rosrun tf view_frames`. The rates are not attached to the frames but to the relationships between them. There is not particular reason why any of them **have** to be faster or slower than any others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I just figured it out:

I was trying to transform a Velocity in the same way as a point from one coordinate frame to another one, but when transforming velocities the vector does not have to be shifted but simply be rotated:

```
void name::transformVelocity(const tf::StampedTransform& transform, const geometry_msgs::Point& vel_in, geometry_msgs::Point& vel_out) const
{
  tf::Point p;
  tf::pointMsgToTF(vel_in, p);

  tf::StampedTransform transform_tmp = transform;
  transform_tmp.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
  p = transform_tmp * p;
  tf::pointTFToMsg(p, vel_out);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Markus](https://answers.ros.org/users/26348/markus/) with karma: 311 on 2018-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1